# SQL for each to join tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I am looking to fill a temporary table:

```
create table #FinalProduct
(
respondentId int,
respondentNumber nvarchar(7),
questionNumber int, 
questionAnswer nvarchar(100)
)
```

So far I have it filled with the respondentIds and respondentNumbers that I want. I then have another temporary table that I pull the question data from:

```
CREATE TABLE #QuestionData
(
QuestionNumber int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
QuestionText nvarchar(255),
QuestionId int
)
insert into #QuestionData values ('This is question # 1', 101)
insert into #QuestionData values ('This is question # 2', 102)
```

I have an answer table in which I use the questionId from the question table to pull the answer from.

```
CREATE TABLE #AnswerData
(
    RespondentNumber nvarchar(7),
QuestionId int,
AnswerText nvarchar(255)
)

insert into #AnswerData values ('9876543',101, 'Answer to #1')
insert into #AnswerData values ('9876543',102, 'Answer to #2')
insert into #AnswerData values ('1234567',101, 'Answer to #1')
insert into #AnswerData values ('1234567',102, 'Answer to #2')
```

Every respondentNumber will have an answer to a question (not all answers will be the same).

I am looking to fill the FinalProduct table so that each respondentNumber has a row for every question and answer. For example the if I have 2 respondentNumbers the final table should look like this:

[image: FinalProductTable]

I don't know if this is meant to be super complex, but I am having a hard time figuring it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance. . .

Comment: can you show the SQL for the CREATE table for the Answers table?

Comment: How do you connect AnswerData to the respondent?

Comment: Yes, there appears to be a very important table missing that lists the respondents and the answers they made.

Comment: Sorry guys, trying to simplify this question as much as possible but failing miserably. Updated my question. Hope it makes sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following create code:

```
CREATE TABLE QuestionData
(
QuestionNumber int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
QuestionText nvarchar(255),
QuestionId int
)
insert into QuestionData values ('This is question # 1', 101)
insert into QuestionData values ('This is question # 2', 102)

CREATE TABLE AnswerData
(
    RespondentNumber nvarchar(7),
QuestionId int,
AnswerText nvarchar(255)
)

insert into AnswerData values ('9876543',101, 'Answer to #1')
insert into AnswerData values ('9876543',102, 'Answer to #2')
insert into AnswerData values ('1234567',101, 'Answer to #1')
insert into AnswerData values ('1234567',102, 'Answer to #2')

create table FinalProduct
(
respondentId int,
respondentNumber nvarchar(7),
questionNumber int, 
questionAnswer nvarchar(100)
)
```

the query:

```
INSERT INTO FinalProduct
SELECT NULL,a.RespondentNumber,q.QuestionNumber,a.AnswerText
FROM AnswerData a
JOIN QuestionData q
ON a.QuestionId=q.QuestionId
ORDER BY RespondentNumber,q.QuestionNumber

GO 
SELECT *
FROM FinalProduct
```

gives:

```
RESPONDENTID    RESPONDENTNUMBER    QUESTIONNUMBER  QUESTIONANSWER
(null)  1234567     1   Answer to #1
(null)  1234567     2   Answer to #2
(null)  9876543     1   Answer to #1
(null)  9876543     2   Answer to #2
```

Sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30592/3

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing data elements, as respondentID isn't in one of your two tables, but I think you're just after a join like this:

```
SELECT respondentNumber, questionNumber ,AnswerText 
FROM AnswerData a
JOIN QuestionData b
 ON a.QuestionId = b.QuestionId
```

You could either select the results into a new table:

```
SELECT respondentNumber, questionNumber ,AnswerText 
INTO #FinalProduct
FROM AnswerData a
JOIN QuestionData b
 ON a.QuestionId = b.QuestionId
```

Or you could INSERT them into your existing table:

```
INSERT INTO #FinalProduct
SELECT respondentNumber, questionNumber ,AnswerText 
FROM AnswerData a
JOIN QuestionData b
 ON a.QuestionId = b.QuestionId
```